# Per user assigned IPv6 addresses for outbound requests

Tags: kubernetes, ipv6, wireguard

I'm running some VMs in a Kubernetes cluster on behalf of my clients. These VMs make occasional requests to external services. This works fine, but the IP address seen by these external services is always the external IP of my cluster making me wonder how one client's activity will affect the others from a IP address reputation point of view.

I am considering renting a /64 IPv6 block that I would then use to assign to each VM an individual IPv6 address. Each VM would have its own public IPv6 address.

One way that I have been exploring is to set up a wireguard server that the VMs would talk to. Something like this: https://gist.github.com/MartinBrugnara/cb0cd5b53a55861d92ecba77c80ba729

But is wireguard even needed? Could I just assign a public IPv6 address from the block to each VM that I am running and not go through wireguard?

Comment: ive never had a usage scenario, but due somekind of documentation from my freelance time, i found for iptables a suggestion like: `ip6tables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d 2001:0db8:1234::1 -m owner --uid-owner username -j MARK --set-mark 1` but i am unsure if that worked in this way

Comment: What do you mean by concerns of "one client's activity will affect the others"? Technical problems with getting address sharing to work? IP address reputation problems when connecting to services you don't control? Edit your question to be specific.

Comment: From a IP address reputation point of view. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Networks should not be made more complicated for the sole purpose of obscuring who you are on the internet. Entities you do business with can identify you and your ISP by IP. Either they respect you and allow traffic, or they don't.

See also on Server Fault: [Should mail servers avoid sharing /64 ipv6 with others for reputation?](https://serverfault.com/q/1103984/241174)

Yes implement IPv6 and join the modern internet, while simplifying by reducing the need for address translation. Have your ISP delegate you some prefix correctly sized for your capacity planning. Your ISP or cloud should be offering native IPv6, which is a better experience than tunneling it in yourself.

I know just enough about Kubernetes to know its a choose-your-own adventure maze of many differing plugins and network designs. Without any information on this network, about all I can say is that as an infrastructure controlling tool, Kubernetes needs to know the IP prefixes it manages.